# I thought the accepted answer is always listed first - here it is second. Huh?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, sorting

How is it possible that this question has the top-voted-but-not-accepted answer listed first, instead of the accepted answer?

[What's the easiest way to get text onto a Kindle?](https://superuser.com/questions/264253/whats-the-easiest-way-to-get-text-onto-a-kindle)

Answer (score 6):

In this case the accepted answer was posted by the person who also asked the question, and self-accepted answers do not receive the preferential treatment during sorting that an accepted answers otherwise would.

This is intentional, and has been the case for self-acceptance [since it was introduced](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/).